# AWS amplify - datastore and file upload offline and sync whenever internet gets

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify with flutter for my application. One of the scenario that I need to create an object along with image/video and save it in the cloud even if there is no internet.

I am using S3 to store the image/video and taking the key from the stored response whenever we have active internet. and saving that stored file's key to the Datastore object and saving the datastore object. this is fine when we have internet connection.

But if there is no internet, still I want to do the same without stopping the user to wait till internet connection available.

The datastore is getting sync sometime if the internet connections gets(only sometimes not every time)

Using flutter how can we achieve?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve Online-/Offline-Support with automated synchronization for your media files you have to implement it yourself.

To do so, you first have to adapt the read and write methods for your media files so they do not only read/write from/to S3 but also from/to the local filesystem. For simplicity reasons I recommend utilizing a similiar structure of your file tree. Thereby, take into consideration that you need some kind of strategy for solving merge-conflicts (e.g. online version changed after offline version).

In addition to that, you have to write a syncing method that checks for all files that require sync (upload and download). For not making your app get stuck it should add all required sync operations to a queue that is handled in the background. The method may be triggered for example on each app-start, every specific time period or on each wake lock.

I faced the same problem some months ago in an open source project. We solved it by creating ower own class SyncedFile and some Repository and Bloc logic to solve the sync. For merge logic we used the last changed value of the files.

```
class SyncedFile {
  SyncedFile(this.path) {
    key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
  }

  String path;

  late Key key;

  Future<File?> file() async {
    File localCacheFile = await getCachePath();
    bool cached = await localCacheFile.exists();
    if (!cached) {
      print("file not in cache, loading it");
      await StorageRepository.downloadFile(localCacheFile, path);
    } else {
      print("found in cache: $path");
    }

    cached = await localCacheFile.exists();

    if (!cached) {
      return null;
    }
    key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    print("returning file: $key");
    return localCacheFile;
  }

  Future<File> getCachePath() async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    List<String> pathParts = path.split("/");
    pathParts.removeAt(pathParts.length - 1);
    String toCreateDir = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < pathParts.length; i++) {
      toCreateDir += pathParts[i];
      if (i != pathParts.length - 1) {
        toCreateDir += "/";
      }
    }
    await Directory(appDocDir.path + "/" + toCreateDir).create(recursive: true);
    File localCacheFile = File('${appDocDir.path}/$path');
    key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    print("returning cache path: $key");
    return localCacheFile;
  }

  Future<void> update(String utf8String) async {
    File localCacheFile = await getCachePath();
    await localCacheFile.writeAsString(utf8String, flush: true);
    StorageRepository.uploadFile(localCacheFile, path);
    key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
  }

  Future<File?> updateAsBytes(File file) async {
    var bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
    File localCacheFile = await getCachePath();
    await localCacheFile.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    StorageRepository.uploadFile(localCacheFile, path);
    print("pic update finished: $key");
    return await getCachePath();
  }

  Future<File?> updateAsPic(XFile xfile) async {
    var bytes = await xfile.readAsBytes();
    File localCacheFile = await getCachePath();
    await localCacheFile.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    print("pic update finished: $key");
    StorageRepository.uploadFile(localCacheFile, path);
    return await getCachePath();
  }

  Future<File?> updateAsAudio(File file) async {
    File localCacheFile = await getCachePath();
    await localCacheFile.writeAsBytes(file.readAsBytesSync(), flush: true);
    await StorageRepository.uploadFile(localCacheFile, path);
    key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    return await getCachePath();
  }

  Future<void> delete() async {
    File localCacheFile = await getCachePath();
    await localCacheFile.delete();
    await StorageRepository.removeFile(path);
    key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
  }

  Future<bool> sync(SyncBloc syncBloc) async {
    try {
      syncBloc.add(StartLoadingFileEvent());
      File localCacheFile = await getCachePath();
      bool cached = await localCacheFile.exists();
      if (!cached) {
        await StorageRepository.downloadFile(localCacheFile, path,
            checkConnection: false);
      } else {
        ListResult listResult = await Amplify.Storage.list(path: path);
        if (listResult.items.isEmpty) {
          StorageRepository.uploadFile(await getCachePath(), path,
              checkConnection: false);
        } else {
          DateTime? lastModifiedLocal;
          try {
            lastModifiedLocal = await localCacheFile.lastModified();
          } catch (e) {}
          DateTime? lastModifiedOnline = listResult.items.first.lastModified;
          if (lastModifiedOnline == null) {
            await StorageRepository.uploadFile(localCacheFile, path,
                checkConnection: false);
          } else if (lastModifiedLocal == null) {
            await StorageRepository.downloadFile(localCacheFile, path,
                checkConnection: false);
          } else if (lastModifiedLocal.isAfter(lastModifiedOnline)) {
            await StorageRepository.uploadFile(localCacheFile, path,
                checkConnection: false);
          } else if (lastModifiedLocal.isBefore(lastModifiedOnline)) {
            await StorageRepository.downloadFile(localCacheFile, path,
                checkConnection: false);
          }
        }
      }
      syncBloc.add(LoadedFileEvent());
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @benedkt, as you said I used own logic to resolve it.